# Почему не работает тест?

Tags: javascript, html, css

При нажатии на кнопку "Ответ" в данном тесте: 1) проверяется соответствие `radio.checked.value`позиции в массиве правильных ответов `tam` (true answer massive), для обозначения индекса в этом массиве использовал переменную `ifm`(index for massive), при ответе на первый вопрос, всё работает корректно, когда отвечаешь на второй вопрос, сравнение почему-то не происходит, как исправить?

```js
var q1 = document.getElementById("question0");
var q2 = document.getElementById("question1");
var q3 = document.getElementById("question2");
var ab = document.getElementById("answerButton");
var index = 0; // переменная для индексирования вопросов (чтобы знать какой сейчас вопрос)
var ifm = 0; // переменная для индексирования позиции в массиве правельных ответов
var tam = [3, 1, 2]; // массив с позициями правильных ответов

window.onload=function(){
  q1.style.display="block"
  q2.style.display="none"
  q3.style.display="none"
};

ab.onclick=function(){
  index++
  document.getElementById("question"+(index-1)).style.display="none"
  document.getElementById("question"+index).style.display="block"

            for(var k=0; k<document.getElementsByClassName("init-group-radio").length; k++){
                if(document.getElementsByClassName("init-group-radio")[k].checked===true){
                    if(document.getElementsByClassName("init-group-radio")[k].value==tam[ifm]){ 
                    // document.getElementsByClassName("init-group-radio")[k].value==tam[ifm] проверяю, что value чекнутого ответа совпадало с позицией в массиве правильных ответов
                      alert("Wright"+"--->"+ifm)
                      ifm++ // т.к. после нажатия на кнопку "Ответ" вопрос уже другой, (т.е. следующий по порядку) то переменная указывающая индекс позиции в массиве правильных ответов инкрементируется
                    }else{
                      alert("Wrong"+"--->"+ifm)
                      ifm++
                    }
                }
            }
};
```

```css
*{
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li{
  list-style: none;
}

body{
  background: black;
}

.question-panel{
  width: 800px;
  height: 500px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 3px #fff;
  margin: 10px;
}

#initGroup{
  margin-top: 10px;
}

/*BUTTON*/
#answerButton{
  width: 70px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #9a9dd5 ;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
  margin-left: 30px;
}
/*BUTTON*/

#listGroupItem{
  display: inline-block;
}

/*span*/
#initGroupSpan{
  margin-right: 20px;
}
/*span*/

.questions{
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!-- MAIN PANEL -->
<div class="question-panel">

        <div id="question0" class="questions">

          <div id="question">
            1) Назовите любой цвет
          </div>

          <div id="answer">
            <div id="initGroup">
              <span id="initGroupSpan"><input class="init-group-radio" value="1" name="0" type="radio"></span>
              <li id="listGroupItem">Зелёный</li>
            </div>
            <div id="initGroup">
              <span id="initGroupSpan"><input class="init-group-radio" value="2" name="0" type="radio"></span>
              <li id="listGroupItem">Красный</li>
            </div>
            <div id="initGroup">
              <span id="initGroupSpan"><input class="init-group-radio" value="3" name="0" type="radio"></span>
              <li id="listGroupItem">Жёлтый</li>
            </div>
            <div id="initGroup">
              <span id="initGroupSpan"><input class="init-group-radio" value="4" name="0" type="radio"></span>
              <li id="listGroupItem">Белый</li>
            </div>
          </div>


        </div>

        <div id="question1" class="questions">
          <div id="question">
            2) Назовите любую цифру
          </div>
          <div id="answer">
            <div id="initGroup">
              <span id="initGroupSpan"><input class="initGroupRadio" value="1" name="1" type="radio"></span>
              <li id="listGroupItem">15</li>
            </div>
            <div id="initGroup">
              <span id="initGroupSpan"><input class="initGroupRadio" value="2" name="1" type="radio"></span>
              <li id="listGroupItem">34</li>
            </div>
            <div id="initGroup">
              <span id="initGroupSpan"><input class="initGroupRadio" value="3" name="1" type="radio"></span>
              <li id="listGroupItem">46</li>
            </div>
            <div id="initGroup">
              <span id="initGroupSpan"><input class="initGroupRadio" value="4" name="1" type="radio"></span>
              <li id="listGroupItem">9</li>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div id="question2" class="questions">
          <div id="question">
            3) Назовите любое животное
          </div>
          <div id="answer">
            <div id="initGroup">
              <span id="initGroupSpan"><input class="initGroupRadio" value="1" name="2" type="radio"></span>
              <li id="listGroupItem">Тигр</li>
            </div>
            <div id="initGroup">
              <span id="initGroupSpan"><input class="initGroupRadio" value="2" name="2" type="radio"></span>
              <li id="listGroupItem">Крокодил</li>
            </div>
            <div id="initGroup">
              <span id="initGroupSpan"><input class="initGroupRadio" value="3" name="2" type="radio"></span>
              <li id="listGroupItem">Лев</li>
            </div>
            <div id="initGroup">
              <span id="initGroupSpan"><input class="initGroupRadio" value="4" name="2" type="radio"></span>
              <li id="listGroupItem">Моя бывшая</li>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div id="answerButton">Ответ</div>

</div>

<!-- MAIN PANEL -->
```

Comment: Ну например, копируете код сюда → https://jsfiddle.net/ а он сразу подсказывает, что id - имя элемента, которое должно быть у него уникальным, и больше не повторяться на странице. getElementById достает первый такой элемент, а остальные игнорирует.

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME , окей, но к сожалению это не решение проблемы, я заменил все `id` на классы в `html`, толку - 0! jsfiddle.net теперь не жалуется, НО и тест мой от этого не начал работать корректно!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Везде заменил id на классы, переписал скрипт для классов. Изначально невидимость вопросов можно записать в CSS, это будет работать быстрее, чем onload. Всем классам "questions" добавил невидимость, + сверху класс `.visi {display: block;}` первому вопросу.

```js
var q = document.querySelectorAll(".questions"); // Получаем все блоки вопросов по классу.
var ab = document.getElementById("answerButton");
var index = 0; // не понял, для чего там ifm, оставил только индекс.

var tam = [3, 1, 2]; 
// Правильные ответы (не забыть, что счет начинается с нуля. Т.е. 3 = 4-й вариант)

ab.onclick = function() {
  // При клике - сразу собираем все радио внутри текущего вопроса q[index]
  var init = q[index].querySelectorAll('.init-group-radio'); 
  
  // tam[index] будет являться номером (индексом) правильного ответа
  // Проверка, если у радио под именно этим номером, есть checked - выбран правильный.
  if (init[tam[index]].checked) {
    alert("Right");
  } else {
    alert("Wrong");
  }

  q[index].classList.remove('visi'); // скрываем вопрос
  index++; // увеличиваем индекс
  if (q[index]) { // Если есть еще следующий вопрос
    q[index].classList.add('visi'); // показываем его
  } else {
    this.style.display = 'none'; // иначе - скрываем кнопку "ответить"
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}

body {
  background: black;
}

.question-panel {
  width: 800px;
  height: 500px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 3px #fff;
  margin: 10px;
}

.initGroup {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

/*BUTTON*/
#answerButton {
  width: 70px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #9a9dd5;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
  margin-left: 30px;
}

/*BUTTON*/

.listGroupItem {
  display: inline-block;
}

/*span*/
.initGroupSpan {
  margin-right: 20px;
}

/* span */

.questions {
  display: none;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.visi {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="question-panel">

  <div class="questions visi">
    <div class="question">
      1) Назовите любой цвет
    </div>

    <div class="answer">
      <div class="initGroup">
        <span class="initGroupSpan"><input class="init-group-radio" value="1" name="0" type="radio"></span>
        <li class="listGroupItem">Зелёный</li>
      </div>
      <div class="initGroup">
        <span class="initGroupSpan"><input class="init-group-radio" value="2" name="0" type="radio"></span>
        <li class="listGroupItem">Красный</li>
      </div>
      <div class="initGroup">
        <span class="initGroupSpan"><input class="init-group-radio" value="3" name="0" type="radio"></span>
        <li class="listGroupItem">Жёлтый</li>
      </div>
      <div class="initGroup">
        <span class="initGroupSpan"><input class="init-group-radio" value="4" name="0" type="radio"></span>
        <li class="listGroupItem">Белый</li>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="questions">
    <div class="question">
      2) Назовите любую цифру
    </div>
    <div class="answer">
      <div class="initGroup">
        <span class="initGroupSpan"><input class="init-group-radio" value="1" name="1" type="radio"></span>
        <li class="listGroupItem">15</li>
      </div>
      <div class="initGroup">
        <span class="initGroupSpan"><input class="init-group-radio" value="2" name="1" type="radio"></span>
        <li class="listGroupItem">34</li>
      </div>
      <div class="initGroup">
        <span class="initGroupSpan"><input class="init-group-radio" value="3" name="1" type="radio"></span>
        <li class="listGroupItem">46</li>
      </div>
      <div class="initGroup">
        <span class="initGroupSpan"><input class="init-group-radio" value="4" name="1" type="radio"></span>
        <li class="listGroupItem">9</li>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="questions">
    <div class="question">
      3) Назовите любое животное
    </div>
    <div class="answer">
      <div class="initGroup">
        <span class="initGroupSpan"><input class="init-group-radio" value="1" name="2" type="radio"></span>
        <li class="listGroupItem">Тигр</li>
      </div>
      <div class="initGroup">
        <span class="initGroupSpan"><input class="init-group-radio" value="2" name="2" type="radio"></span>
        <li class="listGroupItem">Крокодил</li>
      </div>
      <div class="initGroup">
        <span class="initGroupSpan"><input class="init-group-radio" value="3" name="2" type="radio"></span>
        <li class="listGroupItem">Лев</li>
      </div>
      <div class="initGroup">
        <span class="initGroupSpan"><input class="init-group-radio" value="4" name="2" type="radio"></span>
        <li class="listGroupItem">Моя бывшая</li>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="answerButton">Ответ</div>
</div>
```

P.s. пользователи бесятся постоянно скрывать всплывающий alert. Хорошо бы выводить сообщение куда-нибудь в другом месте.

(можно еще считать правильные ответы в процессе... и в конце их показать.)

Comment: Хм, работает ! Обидно, что с моим примером так и не разобрались, ваш вариант конечно более "опытен" чем мой. . . Алерт меня и самого напрягает, НО он нужен мне был просто для проверки, в оригинале я конечно сделаю что-нибудь поинтереснее! Спасибо вам за помощь, но всё же если вы знаете. скажите мне, в чём касяк в моём коде? Я уже просто 100 раз проверил, так и не пойму, почему переменная инкрементируется, НО сравнения значений не происходит . . .

Comment: @Muranx а я тоже сходну не понял. В таких случаях нужно по очереди выводить все получаемые значения, чтобы поймать, где начинается ошибка. https://learn.javascript.ru/ - в 1.4 пункте описывается, как это делается через `console.log()` А у вас главная ошибка оказалась в нумерации. В HTML-элементах value пронумеровано от 1 до 4, а индексы массива начинаются с 0. Вы сравнивали `init[k].value == tam[ifm]` а надо было `init[k].value - 1 == tam[ifm]`. Помимо этого - в одном месте у вас init-group-radio, в другом InitGroupRadio... https://jsfiddle.net/OPTlMUS/qnu5Lagt/ - так работает...

Comment: Ну и искать радио нужно было внутри текущего вопроса (что неудобно по id), а не по всей странице.

Comment: сейчас перешёл по вашей ссылке, к сожалению опаздываю на работу, чот и ваш пример не работает, т.к. массив с правильными ответами `[3, 1, 2]` , а при клике в первом вопросе на чек бокс `3` выдаёт `Wrong`, ну и соотвественно остальные тоже не совпадают

Comment: Код правильный, массив неправильный) Все проблемы из-за нумерации... надо определиться, и весь код писать или для нумерации начиная от 1, или от 0... чтобы не было путанницы. В JS счет начинается с нуля... поэтому ваш [3, 1, 2] означает [4-й вариант, 2-й вариант, 3-й вариант]. Можно или в цикле это учитывать и на месте делать "минус 1", или, если удобнее указывать варианты в формате "1-2-3-4", написать массив так, но добавить малюсенькую функцию, которая заранее пройдется по массиву и отнимит у каждого элемента -1.

Comment: блин, то ли я с просони, то ли я реально не понимаю. `document.getElementsByClassName("init-group-radio")[k].value==tam[ifm]` в этой строчке в моём коде я сравниваю значение (value) чекнутого ответа, ну допустим оно равно 3, СО значением НУЛЕВОГО элемента массива, т.е. `[3,1,2]` т.е. с тройкой, и всё работает, о чем вы говорите? Какие -1? Всё же работает в первом варианте ответа, почему дальше то не работает? Хоть убей не понимаю, какие там надо -1 делать, если мы сравниваем `value`, с позицией в массиве, когда ifm инкрементируется, мы уже сравниваем 2 позиц. массива с чеком второго вопроса !

Comment: и пожалуйста на будущее, если вы вставляете в коммент ссылку на мой переделанный код, будьте добры сделать так, чтобы он работал, а то получается что вы вставили, а код не рабочий, и это ещё сильнее запутывает, когда вы в комментарии пытаетесь объяснить то, что (если я вас правильно понял решается) с помощь добавления "-1" в коде! Когда я задаю вопрос, это означает что я что-то не вижу, или не допонимаю, а вы вставляете ещё и не рабочий код, что ещё больше усугубляет ситуацию